# Default template parameters in using-declaration and instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17

*Edit:*
Apparently, GCC allows instantiating a class template without a parameter list (when the parameters are defaulted), which is non-compliant (Clang is compliant).
I'm guessing the reason for requiring the brackets (even when the parameter list is empty) is to make it explicit that it is a template instantiation, as opposed to an actual type.
So I am steering my original question toward the differences between the class template and function template cases: why, in the second snippet, is it allowed to call a without brackets, in contrast to the instantiation of A in the first snippet? And why is it not allowed for b?

---

*Original:*
A class template with only default parameters can be instantiated without any parameter list (see A below).
However, if an alias to that class template is defined via a using-declaration as a template with the same default parameters (see B below), then its instantiation requires a parameter list (possibly empty).
Similarly, defining an alias to the class template as an actual type (see C below) requires a parameter list (again, possibly empty).
Is there a reason behind this?

```
template<int i = 1>
struct A {
    operator int() { return i; }
};

template<int i = 2>
using B = A<i>;

// using C = A;    <-- error: missing template arguments after 'A'
using C = A<>;

int main() {
    A a; // Edit: Actually should require brackets: A<> a;
    // B b;    <-- error: missing template arguments before 'b'
    B<> b;
    C c;
}
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4768802eb25bfa9b)

I have tried building a similar scenario with a function template instead of a class template, and there is a slight difference in the last case (C): no parameter list is required if the return type is specified in the definition of `a`. I think I understand why, but I would welcome some insights. Otherwise, both cases are similar to the class template ones.

```
template<int i = 1>
auto a() { return i; }
// auto a() -> int { return i; }
// if the return type is specified, c can be defined as commented below

template<int i = 2>
auto b = a<i>;

// auto c = a;    <-- error: unable to deduce 'auto' from 'a'
auto c = a<>;

int main() {
    a();
    // b();    <-- error: missing template arguments before '(' token
    b<>();
    c();
}
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9aaf82b661807749)

Also, are there significant differences between modern C++ standards (C++11 to C++20)? I am mostly interested in the C++17 case, but I would love to know if these things have changed, or are going to.
From what I've seen, in C++14, a class template instantiation requires a parameter list anyway, whereas a function template call does not. And I haven't found differences between C++17 and C++2a with GCC.

Comment: Coliru uses an slightly outdated clang (5.0.0, the latest release is 7.0.0), which doesn't implement some Defect Reports concerning [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction).

Comment: @cpplearner I don't quite see what part this is supposed to affect. Clang seems compliant to me?

Comment: Which clang, clang 5.0.0 or clang 7.0.0 (which allows `A a;`)?

Comment: @cpplearner Oh, so Clang 7.0.0 allows the same as GCC, which is non-compliant? Is that just something both compilers added for convenience, or is it a bug in both? Or is it in fact supposed to be allowed by the standard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Template arguments [temp.arg]/4 (§12.3/4)](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#arg-4)

> When template argument packs or default template-arguments are used, a *template-argument list* can be empty. **In that case the empty `<>` brackets shall still be used as the *template-argument-list***.

Same wording for C++17 in §17.3/4, for C++14 & C++11 in §14.3/4.

[Explicit template argument specification [temp.arg.explicit] (§12.9.1/3)](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.fct.spec#temp.arg.explicit-3):

> If all of the template arguments can be deduced, they may all be omitted; in this case, the empty template argument list `<>` itself may also be omitted.

Same wording for C++17 in §17.8.1/3, for C++14 & C++11 in §14.8.1/3.

---

Your

> ```
> template<int i = 2>
> auto b = a<i>;
> ```

is a *variable template* for which no argument deduction will occur.

Comment: So is that a GCC "bug" to allow omitting the brackets? What about the function template case?

Comment: Alright it does look like a bug with GCC since Clang doesn't allow it in the class template case. It does with function templates though. Any reason behing that difference?

Comment: Maybe add another simple example of what clang allows and you worry about in your question? btw. You are aware that `auto c = a<>;` defines a function pointer `a`?

Comment: I am aware that c is a function pointer (as is b). Is there anything closer to an alias for functions?

Comment: @Nelfeal Not really. Just asked to make sure. Your `b` is a variable template, though.

Comment: So, if I'm getting this right, the difference is actually between three cases: class templates, function templates, and variable templates. And for some reason, function template instantiations are the only ones which do not require brackets when the arguments are deduced. And if there are default values, then the arguments are indeed deduced. Is that correct?

Comment: @Nelfeal AFAICT Yes.